# Renaming png fails with shutter

Tags: command-line, image-processing, batch-rename, png, shutter

I am learning to use `shutter` and from the CLI I was trying to take 10 screenshots at 1 second interval and to rename them, however when I try I get an error message that says: "There was an error determining the filename.", and nothing is saved.

The command I'm using is this one:

```
for i in {1..10}; do shutter -d 1 -f -o $name_%NN.png -e; done
```

I would like `shutter` to name all the pictures taken in a sequential order, for example:

- `1.png`
- `2.png`
- `3.png`

and so on.

Also (I am not sure if I can add an extra command to this) I would like to move all the pictures to a specific folder, for example: `~/Desktop/School` (from the current location `~/MyPictures`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing a `$name` variable which doesn't exists within your script's scope, the number you want to use to build the filename is stored in the `$i` variable:

```
for i in {1..10}; do shutter -d 1 -f -o ${i}.png -e; done
```

Notice that I've enclosed the reference to `$i` between brackets, this is safer when concatenating strings.

To move all the screenshots taken to `~/Desktop/School` you can run this command:

```
mv *.png ~/Desktop/School
```

And to make this second command execute automatically upon success of the first one, you can chain it to the first one using the `&&` operator:

```
for i in {1..10}; do shutter -d 1 -f -o ${i}.png -e; done && mv *.png ~/Desktop/School
```